# Using variable outside Try-Catch

Tags: c#

I need to use the value of a variable initialized inside a try block. I have this basic code

```
Customer customer = null;
try
{
    customer = new Customer(....);
}
catch (Exception){}
string customerCode = customer.Code;
```

If there is no exception, the customer is perfecly usable, but if there is an exception, customer is not initialized, it returns null

I have checked that customer ALLWAYS initializes correctly INSIDE the block. INSIDE It is perfectly usable even in case of exception. But I need it for later use.

Any way to ALLWAYS keep the customer? :)

**EDIT:**

As you supposed, this was pseudocode. As I can read, it looks like to use exceptions in constructors is a BAD idea. This is part of my REAL code for my constructor.

```
public class DirectDebitRemmitanceReject
{
    int numberOfTransactions;
    decimal controlSum;
    List<DirectDebitTransactionReject> directDebitTransactionRejects;

    public DirectDebitRemmitanceReject(
        int numberOfTransactions,
        decimal controlSum, 
        List<DirectDebitTransactionReject> directDebitTransactionRejects)
    {
        this.numberOfTransactions = numberOfTransactions;
        this.controlSum = controlSum;
        this.directDebitTransactionRejects = directDebitTransactionRejects;

        if (TheProvidedNumberOfTransactionsIsWrong()) ChangeNumberOfTransactionsAndRiseException();
        if (TheProvidedControlSumIsWrong()) ChangeControlSumAndRiseException();
    }

    private bool TheProvidedNumberOfTransactionsIsWrong()
    {
        return (numberOfTransactions != directDebitTransactionRejects.Count)
    }

    private bool TheProvidedControlSumIsWrong()
    {
        return (controlSum !=directDebitTransactionRejects.Select(ddRemmitanceReject => ddRemmitanceReject.Amount).Sum();)
    }

    private void ChangeNumberOfTransactionsAndRiseException()
    {
        ......
        ......
        throw new ArgumentException(exceptionMessage, "numberOfTransactions")

    private void ChangeControlSumAndRiseException()
    {
        ......
        ......
        throw new ArgumentException(exceptionMessage, "controlSum")
    } 
}
```

In the methods 'TheProvided...' I check if the arguments are congruent with the sum of values in the list. If not, I update them and inform by raising an ArgumentException

The fact is that I wanted the constructor ALLWAYS returns a valid (congruent) DirectDebitRemmitanceReject, but desired the same constructor to rise the exception if provided wrong numberOfTransactions or controlSum. NumberOfTransactions and controlSum should not be modified later, only readed.

In my tests, this works well

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(System.ArgumentException))]
    public void IfTheProvidedControlSumInARemmitanceRejectIsWorgAnExceptionIsThrown()
    {
        try
        {
            DirectDebitRemmitanceReject directDebitRemmitanceReject = new DirectDebitRemmitanceReject(
                originalDirectDebitRemmitance1MessageID,
                2,
                100,
                directDebitTransactionRejectsList1);
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentException e)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("controlSum", e.ParamName);
            Assert.AreEqual("The Control Sum is wrong. Provided: 100. Expected: 150. Initialized with expected value", e.GetMessageWithoutParamName());
            throw;
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IfTheProvidedControlSumInARemmitanceRejectIsWorgItIsCorrected()
    {
        try
        {
            DirectDebitRemmitanceReject directDebitRemmitanceReject = new DirectDebitRemmitanceReject(
                originalDirectDebitRemmitance1MessageID,
                2,
                100,
                directDebitTransactionRejectsList1);
            Assert.AreEqual(150, directDebitRemmitanceReject.ControlSum);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException) { }
    }
```

But i can,t Assert the directDebitRemmitanceReject.ControlSum outside the 'try' block

So... do I try another aproach (remove the exception from inside the constructor) or is there another workaround?

Thanks! :)

(Sorry for the EXTENSIVE edit) :(

Comment: That means the try didn't execute that statement. Variables do not lose their value after a try block. You likely had an exception. If you post your actual code, we can probably help. Judging by the looks of that code (especially since a constructor shouldn't throw an exception) I'm assuming it's pseudocode.

Comment: You probably want to look at what you are doing in your constructor.  Your constructor should ideally not throw an exception.

Comment: If you always need the customer, why not drop `try`-`catch`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Why would that be helpful at all? A try/catch doesn't clear values.

Comment: Are you completely sure it always initializes correctly? I'm pretty sure you're wrong. Please start by posting a [MCVE]

Comment: @dman2306 Why `catch` and swallow an exception if you really need that instance of `Customer`. Catch-all is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I agree swallowing exceptions is bad. However, a catch block is not the reason why `customer == null` The reason is an exception is being thrown somewhere. You want to treat the symptom (a try/catch) instead of the disease (why is an exception being thrown?)

Comment: As you supossed, this was pseudocode. I have added the base code of my REAL constructor. You can see I check the arguments, and if not correct, the constructor solves the incoungruence, returning allways a valid instance, throwing and ArgumentException at the end. Is that an invalid aproach? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If it throws an exception it isn't "returning a valid instance" it's throwing an exception. It can't do both. And in general, it is considered bad design to throw exceptions in a constructor.

Comment: Add a property like a list of Warnings or something (these don't sound like errors since you want everything to continue to work even when this happens?). Then read that later. Without understanding your code in much greater detail it's hard to suggest a design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is a perfect illustration of why writing

```
catch (Exception){}
```

is a very bad practice.

When you catch an exception, you are supposed to do something about it. If you do not know what to do with an exception in a particular method of your code, don't catch the exception in that method.

If you always need a customer, even when its retrieval causes an exception, add some code to the `catch` block to set `customer` variable to some default object:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception) {
    customer = Customer.Unknown;
}
```

This assumes that `Customer` has a property `Unknown` of type `Customer` with some default behavior.

> **Comment:** Needed to warn the upper level of my code. Just, when I create an instance, create it, but warn the arguments where wrong. Could you recommend me some better approach?

Make a factory for validating users while creating them:

```
class CustomerCreationResult {
    public Customer Customer() { get; set; }
    public CustomerCreationError Error() { get; set; }
}

class CustomerFactory {
    public CustomerCreationResult CreateCustomer(String name, int age) { ... }
}
```

Now you can create your customers as follows:

```
var r = myCustomerFactory.CreateCustomer(name, age);
if (r.getError() != null) {
    ... // Present the error
}
Customer customer = r.Customer;
...
```

Comment: Sorry. I used pseudo code without explaining the real behavior of my constructor. I have edited my example and added it. I wanted to use exception to SIGNAL there was an argument error during initialization, even when the constructor solves it. May be an exception is not the best way to handle this. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: @Kaikus Exceptions should be used for non-recoverable situations. If you would like to warn the user of a recoverable mistake, use a different mechanism for reporting your warning.

Comment: Needed to warn the upper level of my code. Just, when I create an instance, create it, but warn the arguments where wrong. Could you recomend me some better approach? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much!. I'll use this aproach :)

Answer (score 0):

If customer always initializes correctly, then why do you have it in the try block?

If you want to persist it when an exception occurs, either move the initialization of customer outside of the try block or use try/catch for smaller chunks of code.

for example:

```
Customer customer = null;
try
{
    //in this block do the stuff that is unlikely to cause exceptions
    customer = new Customer(...);

    try
    {
         //stuff that is likely to cause exceptions
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         //handle likely errors
    }
catch (Exception e)
{
    //handle the unusual errors
}
```

Comment: *If customer always initializes correctly, then why do you have it in the try block?* Why do you have exception handling at all? To handle *exceptions*. That one time it doesn't work.

Comment: *If you want to persist it when an exception occurs...*, that is impossible. If the constructor fails you don't have an instance at all.

Comment: In theory, any call to `new` could fail with an `OutOfMemoryException` so there is never a way to 100% guarantee it _always_ initializes correctly. Usually once you hit an OOM exception you're done for, but the point is an exception can happen on that line and hence a `try`/`catch` isn't 100% stupid.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. But according to his initial post, customer always initializes correctly. If there is a part in his method that is more likely to create problems, then that part needs to be handled in a way so that his outer try block doesn't fail.

Comment: @AdamP yes, and as seasoned developers it's up to us to inform him he can't guarantee something _always_ works, as he is dealing with a device that has limitations beyond his control. Remember, he is here to learn. If his statement was true that it always initialized correctly, then it would never be null and he wouldn't be here. Hence, he is incorrect.

Comment: Ok. I wanted to use exception to SIGNAL there was an error during initialization. As you can see in my edited code, just to warn of an argument error that upper levels should know. But, in any case, the instance is correctly created. A better way to signal this? May be a simple event?

Answer (score -1):

I think 'dasblinkenlight's answer is very good, but for the simplest purpose an `if` would be enough:

```
string customerCode = "";
if (customer!=null)
{
    customerCode = customer.Code;
}
```

And you really should check the exception...

Comment: I'm not sure what this means or how it solves the problem?

Comment: I don't recall his question mentioning any `NullReferenceException`, he asked why is it null.